# Very thin white line in colortbl

Tags: colortbl

Whenever I use the `colortbl` package to format tables, a thin white space between the cells sometimes shows up on screen (not in print for as far as I can tell). For example in this table:

[image]

Is there an easy way to enlarge each rectangle by a tiny amount so that the white space is not visible anymore?

(My guess is that the white space appears due to rounding in my pdf viewer, `evince`. I don't know if other pdf viewers have the same issue. Regardless, I would like to have my pdf file look good in common pdf readers)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes this is due to the coloured panels being snapped to pixel boundaries.

You can go  `\\\noalign{\vskip-0.1pt}` for a suitably small amount between each row, then the panels will overlap and you are less likely to get a gap. You can add set `\extrarowheight` to something large to compensate (which is probably a good idea anyway, to keep the capital letters away from the top of the panels)

That is for horizontal lines. For vertical lines `\rowcolor` has optional arguments to specify optional left and right overhang.

Comment: Awesome, works like a charm! Maybe this could be default behavior of colortbl?

Comment: Can't really make it the default, it's inherent in the way TeX handles color really, a "small" overlap between tow large panels isn't noticeable but if you have a 0.4pt `\hline` between them overlapping by 0.1pt is probably too much. You can get the same behaviour without colortbl just use something like `\fcolorbox` Tex will specify that the coloured panel and the border are adjacent but some viewers my snap them apart by a pixel.

Comment: I see. Perhaps a length parameter could be added to the `colortbl` package, which can be set by the user to enlarge each background by a small overlap?

Comment: yes that's a possibility, I'll think about it...

Answer (score 1):

The package `nicematrix` provides tools specially designed to solve that problem. The output is perfect in all the PDF viewers, at all levels of zoom.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{NiceTabular}{cccwl{8cm}}
\CodeBefore
  \columncolor{gray}{1}     
  \rowcolor{gray}{1}
  \rectanglecolor{lightgray}{2-2}{2-4}
  \rectanglecolor{lightgray}{2-2}{6-2}
  \rectanglecolor{gray}{3-3}{3-4}
  \rectanglecolor{gray}{3-3}{7-3}
  \cellcolor{black}{7-2,8-2,8-3}
\Body
  & \Block[l]{1-3}{\color{white}Property 1} \\
  & & \Block[l]{1-2}{Property 2} \\
  $\blacktriangledown$ & & & \color{white}Property 3 \\
  & $\blacktriangledown$ \\
  & & $\blacktriangledown$ & \bfseries Part 1 \\
  $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & 1. Step one \\
  \hline
  $\bullet$ & \color{white} $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & 2. Step two \\
  \hline
  $\bullet$ & \color{white} $\bullet$ & \color{white} $\bullet$ & 3. Step three \\
  \hline
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]