# Remove space between table cell

Tags: tables, colortbl

I want to add background color to my table, but do not want any borders

```
\documentclass[12pt, landscape]{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
  \begin{tabular}{cl}
  \rowcolor{black}
  \textcolor{white}{A}  &  \textcolor{white}{B} \\
  \rowcolor{black}
  \textcolor{white}{a} & \textcolor{white}{b} \\
  \end{tabular}
\end {table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see there is a very thin line which appears between the columns and rows, which I believe is due to the space between cells. I do not want these lines.

How to remove them?

Thanks.

-Alok

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! On my system I can't reproduce the issue you describe as I get the following output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/px4ba.png

Comment: This is strange. I just checked again and have updated a complete code that I used to generate the above table. I am still seeing the borders.
I am generating the pdf on OverLeaf using pdflatex compiler.

Comment: Probably related: [Very thin white line in colortbl](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53576/134144) and [remove thin white line in dark-colored cells](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/380946/134144)

Comment: Thank You. Adding \noalign{\vskip-0.1pt} for rows and [\dimexpr\tabcolsep+0.1pt\relax]  for columns solved my problem.