# Very thin white lines in \fcolorbox

Tags: colortbl

I see `\fcolorbox` making very thin white lines between the border of a box and the dark background and at the corners of the border. Here is an example:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\begin{document}

\fcolorbox{black}{black}{\quad}

\end{document}
```

When enlarged, the result looks like the following when viewed in macOS `Preview.app`:

[image: zoomin]

How can I remove those lines for `\fcolorbox`? Thanks.

[Remove thin white line in dark colored cells](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/380946/remove-thin-white-line-in-dark-colored-cells) and [Very thin white line in colortbl](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53576/very-thin-white-line-in-colortbl) deal with the problem for `\columncolor`.

Comment: Rendering problem ---  `okular` and  `evince` show lines or not depending on the magnification. I tend to blame antialiasing algorithms normally (well, basically the exception to the antialiasing algorithm that is added to avoid wiping out sub-pixel lines, that is).

Comment: There is no point using `\fcolorbox` with the same color for the background and the frame. You should use `\colorbox` instead and you will never have thin white lines since you will have only *one* colored rectangle...

Comment: Oh, I used the same color to make the lines clear and noticeable. But, anyway, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a rendering problem --- `okular` and `evince` show lines or not depending on the magnification. I tend to blame antialiasing algorithms normally (well, basically the exception to the antialiasing algorithm that is added to avoid wiping out sub-pixel lines, that is).

[image]

...this is what each one of the viewers *thinks* it's a 400% zoom .

You can try to see if a Ti*k*Z equivalent (which draws the background in a different way) comes out more resilient to the problem.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\tikzcolorbox}[3]{\tikz[baseline]\node[fill=#1,draw=#2]{#3 };}
\begin{document}

\fcolorbox{black}{black}{\quad\textcolor{white}{Text}\quad}

\tikzcolorbox{black}{black}{\quad\textcolor{white}{Text}\quad}

\end{document}
```

It seems to fix the problem at least in evince:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Would there be a way to enlarge the background part marginally (like the `overhang` option of `\cellcolor`) so that white lines are hidden on all viewers?

Comment: No, sorry, I don't know it. But what do you need to put into the `\framebox`? Because if you just want a black blob maybe a `\vrule` will work much better.

Comment: Thanks. It was just an example. I have put texts in many `\fcolorbox`s in a document and some people noticed and mentioned (complained about) the white lines. I was wondering if I could `\renewcommand` it somehow. Anyway I'm glad it's a viewer problem.

Comment: I added a possible Ti*k*Z solution --- it fixes the problem in `evince`, YMMV....

Comment: Superb! Thanks!